# How to train a Keras sequential model without target data?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence, data-science, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to use Keras to build a 1Dconvolution model for timeseries data. However, in this instance, I would like to use a Reinforcement Learning method. In this way, I do not need a target data because I use a custom loss function to calculate the loss based on the previous step's output. Then the optimizer will work on minimizing the custom loss.

In my scenario, the epochs batch_size are equal to 1, the gradient will be backpropagated immediately after each sample input.

Problem: model.fit() in Keras requires input and target output to calculate the loss and gradient, How can I skip target value and just feed in the input data and receive the output to pass to my loss function?

Thank you

Comment: Curious if you have no target data, what exactly are you optimizing?

Comment: instead of feeding the data in batches and compute the loss between the output and the target label, the network's output which is a probability distribution will trigger an action with strength relative to the output. This action will then change the state of the environment in the next step. Instead of the loss function, I have a reward function which computes how good is the new state in comparison to the previous state and sends a reward signal proportionally. The optimizer will send the gradient signal to maximize total reward over the runtime by minimizing -1*reward.

Comment: Hmm, Im really not familiar with that type of learning, but I think this package, built on top of keras is what your looking for ([Edwards](https://github.com/blei-lab/edward))

Comment: Thanks anyway, I think I figured it out. Keras passes the Y_target to chosen Loss function and that's the only place which it will be used and then passes the loss to optimizer. I could work around this by passing the previous state of the environment as the Y_target, so when it compiles the model it wont raise an argument error and I can pass the pervious state from the compile to my loss function and then the optimizer. I'll test this and share the update if it works.